# Command Binding without parameter

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am in the process of learning MVVM in WPF.

How would I go about binding a command to a control, without that command taking an object parameter?  I am currently making use of the RelayCommand approach, and this will not allow me to pass a Method/Action without the object parameter, as specified by the Action signature within the RelayCommand class.

So my question is, if I wanted to implement commands without taking any parameters, what would my approach be?

Comment: Can we see the code that you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DelegateCommand` included in the [Microsoft Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) libraries.

This command allows you to define any parameter type you need.

For example

```
ICommand MyCommand = new DelegateCommand<AnyType>(Execute, CanExecute);

private void Execute(AnyType e) {} private bool CanExecute(AnyType e) { return true; }
```

or, the example you need:

```
ICommand MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute);

private void Execute() {} private bool CanExecute() {return true;}
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the `RelayCommand` myself, preferring to use my own implementation, but I think that they are similar enough for me to be able to answer your question:

```
public ICommand ActivateCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(action => Activate(), canExecute => CanActivate()); }
}
```

Here, the `CommandParameter` is represented by the `action` and `canExecute` input parameters. You *must* declare them here, but you don't *have* to use them, as you can see above. Obviously, as with all lambda expressions, you can call them what you like.