# How to access CodeActivity In Argument Value in Code Behind

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation

Can Someone please help me how to access Code Activity's InArgument in CodeBehind of xaml designer

I am trying to play around with Activity Designer for understanding
From other posts on stack overflow I learned to use ModelItem is used for accessing argument values of CodeActivity in Xaml

But How to access the values in code behind ?

```
    [Designer(typeof(ActivityDesigner1))]
public class Class1 : CodeActivity
{   
public InArgument<String> FirstName { get; set; }
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    // Activity Action Logic
}
}
```

Here is the Activity Designer XAML

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50">
            </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="MyBtn" Grid.Row="0" Text = "{Binding Path=ModelItem.FirstName, 
Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter},ConverterParameter=In, 
Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="OnTextChange" />
</Grid>
```

And Here is the code Behind

```
public partial class ActivityDesigner1
{
    public ActivityDesigner1()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void OnTextChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     // WANT TO ACCESS FirstName  HERE
    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you set your ViewModel as DataContext? From this DataContext you may access the FirstName.

Comment: Can you @DanielW. guide me on how to do this, As I am new to this. I have tried this.DataContext = this after IntializeComponent() but  have no idea what that does

Comment: Is there any specail reason to do this with an Code Activity? As it belongs to WindowWorkflowFoundation? I would normally do this with a command binding. like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119055/command-binding-without-parameter

Comment: @DanielW. thank you for replying . I use UiPath and for that I want to create custom activities. I think its based on Workflow Foundation and we can use Activity designer to design custom activities, thats why I was playing with it. I will Also check the IComand you talked about.